# Access Denied exception when calling Windows Phone 8.1 ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Using following tutorial from MSDN i am trying to retrieve contacts. But getting Access denied exception. [Quickstart: Selecting user contacts Windows Phone Store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631246.aspx)

PS: I am using windows phone 8.1 universal app.

I am getting exception at following line

```
 ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
```

and below is the exception stack trace

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at App3.Members.d__0.MoveNext()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Requirements section in the documentation of ContactStore class [documentation of ContactStore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.personalinformation.contactstore.aspx).

Edit WMAppManifest.xaml and add `ID_CAP_CONTACTS` capability.

Comment: Thanks alot lisp:) it missed that.