# Accessing Contact Information in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I an using the following code as per the links i read in MSDN.

```
 public async void getFavouriteList()
    {
        try
        {
            ContactStore store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();


            var queryOptions = new ContactQueryOptions();
            queryOptions.DesiredFields.Add(KnownContactProperties.DisplayName);

            ContactQueryResult result = store.CreateContactQuery(queryOptions);

            var contactCount = await result.GetContactCountAsync();
            var contacts = await result.GetContactsAsync(0, contactCount);

            //IReadOnlyList<StoredContact> contacts = await result.GetContactsAsync();

            foreach (StoredContact item in contacts)
            {
                // I am not getting any contacts so this debug line is not printed !!!
                Debug.WriteLine("this is not printed");

                Debug.WriteLine(item.DisplayName + ":" + item.RemoteId);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("this is not printed 7");
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Please Indicate Problems in my code .

Things to note 
I am using the Windows 8.1 universal App template.
I have also added Contacts as well as Appointments to my application  capabilities.

Every thing looks perfect to me .. please help me if i am missing something !!

Comment: has Anyone tried with the Contact accessing in the Universal Apps Am I missing something Please Help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can certainly do it.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
    picker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactFieldType.Email);
    var contact = await picker.PickContactAsync();

    if (contact == null)
        return;

#if WINDOWS_APP
    var button = sender as Button;
    var visual = button.TransformToVisual(null);
    var point = visual.TransformPoint(new Windows.Foundation.Point());
    var rect = new Windows.Foundation.Rect(point, button.RenderSize);
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactManager.ShowContactCard(contact, rect);
#elif WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(contact.DisplayName);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
#endif
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you've written is only pulling contacts that are specific to your application.

If you're trying to get all of the contacts on the device, you'll probably want to do something more like this:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts;

var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

foreach (var contact in contacts) 
{
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: This throws `Access denied` exception on my Windows Phone Silverlight app.

Comment: I think this is for universal app and not for silverlight app. You can try declaring capability in the manifest file for the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367555/access-denied-exception-when-calling-windows-phone-8-1-contactmanager-requeststo