# Get Contact List 8.1 Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new on windows phone 8.1 development. I have the following problem. I'm trying to get the contact list from the phone and display it in some ListBox (wpf). I tried the samples from Microsoft but with no luck. Does anyone have a method to get the contact list in C#?

Ok then:

I have a button event on clik and on that event i using the following code:

```
        ContactStore contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();

        IReadOnlyList<Contact> contacts = null;
        // Find all contacts
        contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

        foreach (var item in contacts)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.LastName))
            {
                var acontact = new Contact() { Name = item.FirstName + " " + item.MiddleName + " " + item.LastName, };

                myContacts.Add(acontact);
            }
        }
```

and i get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: What do you mean, you tried the samples with no luck? What samples? What's wrong with them?

Comment: I tried contact binding sample and it's not working.

Comment: `it's not working` so fix it. That's about the most specific advice anyone can give you if you're not going to explain *how* it's not working or show any code...

Comment: i asked if anyone can tell me a method in C# to get the contact list. Do you know any methods?

Comment: Maybe this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367555/access-denied-exception-when-calling-windows-phone-8-1-contactmanager-requeststo) page will help?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @AWinkle please write the answer down to mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [access-denied-exception-when-calling-windows-phone-8-1-contactmanager-requeststo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367555/access-denied-exception-when-calling-windows-phone-8-1-contactmanager-requeststo) it looks like you need to edit `WMAppManifest.xam` and add `ID_CAP_CONTACTS` capability.